# 433 MHz Transceiver - understanding OOK demodulator parameter 'OokFixedThreshold'

Tags: rf, radio, transceiver, demodulation, 433mhz

I would appreciate some help to understand a parameter for this device https://www.semtech.com/products/wireless-rf/fsk-transceivers/sx1231h. I'm far from an expert at RF matters and this question has left me stumped - not even google has been able to help me out.

Section 3.4.12 of the data sheet speaks about the OOK demodulator. In order to effectively set-up the demodulator the noise floor of the receiver ('OokFixedthreshold') should be programmed into register 0x1D 'RegOokFix'. There's a simple procedure to determine the value to be programmed in reg 0x1D. I've followed the procedure, everything works fine, no issues with the receiver. The value I use is 0x60 / 96 dB.

However, I have no idea what this value represents. The description of the reg in section 6.4 says the value of the reg is in dB. A dB is a ratio. So, my question is, from what reference point? The noise threshold is 96 dB up or down from where? There's no clarity in the data sheet to help.

The RSSI value with no transmissions is between -80 dBm and -82 dBm. The device is in continuous receive mode and reg 'RegRssiThresh' is wound right down so the received goes straight into 'RxReady'.

Comment: I am reading the value is only 6 (0101) mean -6dB or 50% of peak

Comment: Thanks @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75. I wondered if it was peak RSSI, but then considered the peak value in dBm is going to change dependant on the power and distance of the tx source. This value is intended to be fixed, at least that's my read.

Comment: It's probably from some arbitrary reference point.  If it starts at 0dB and goes down, it's probably the maximum possible unsaturated magnitude the RSSI can "see".  It's *not* going to be with reference to the transmitter -- it's only going to be referenced to what's happening on your board, from the antenna inward.

Comment: Using OOK on 433MHz isn't a great idea. You can easily be disrupted by others since its a public, license-free band. Anything that doesn't use narrowband FSK is eventually going to be jammed out. Don't make the same mistake as Volvo did when they launched broadband ASK modulated remote car keys on 433MHz. It worked fine until someone unexpectedly got the idea to park their car in a city...

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @Lundin, and the Volvo story, that's made me smile today. I have some sensors out on the network already that use a cheap 'bit bashed' OOK tx. If it wasn't for this I'd have gone FSK for sure.

Comment: @Smarties Another concern might be that if the solution isn't narrowband < 25kHz channel distance, then you have a 10% duty cycle requirement on the band in many countries in Europe. For a device that spends most of the time asleep, that's not a problem, but it will be a problem if you need to send continuously.

Comment: Thanks @Lundin. Fortunately these are just sensors popping up for 50 ms once a minute, or once every 5 mins.

Answer (score 1):

The Y axis on the graph illustrating demodulator threshold settings is labeled "RSSI [dBm]" which suggests the dB value in `RegOokFix` is relative to some RSSI value, the question is *what* value?

RSSI values go from 0 dBm (RssiValue = 0x00) to -127.5 dBm (`RssiValue` = 0xFF). The procedure recommended to optimize `OokFixedThresh` (shown in the flow chart in Figure 12.) is to monitor data output starting with the default `OokFixedThresh` setting of 6 dB and incrementing it until there is no glitching. This implies incrementing `RegOokFix` **increases** the threshold level above the minimum RSSI level of -127.5 dBm, eg. -127.5dBm + 6 dBm = -121.5 dBm.

However you say,

> I've followed the procedure, everything works fine, no issues with the
> receiver. The value I use is 0x60 / 96 dB.

-127.5 dBM + 96 dB = -31.5 dBm. If I have interpreted the datasheet correctly then your receiver should have very low sensitivity in 'peak threshold' mode.

Comment: Thanks @Bruce Abbott. Your rational has got me thinking, in terms of this dB value and it's relation to the RSSI measure - the demodulator is fed from the RSSI block. When the RSSI value is read it needs to be halved. An RSSI value is also used to trigger the AGC, again the value applied has to be doubled. If we apply half of the 96dB to the min RSSI range of -115 dBm, the threshold would be -67 dBM. Still above the noise floor, but starting to make a little more sense. Thanks.